# Add to google calendar button (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, calendar

Help is needed. I can't figure out how to set a link to Google calendar on the button, which is generated from custom fields. I found the code that works properly, configured ACF, but how to write the final URL on the custom button. Is it possible to store this generated URL in a custom field?

```
<?php 
$format = "Ymd\THis\Z";
$starttime = get_field('start');
$endtime = get_field('end');
$eventstart = date($format , $starttime);
$eventend = date($format , $endtime);?>

<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?
action=TEMPLATE
&text=<?php the_title(); ?>
&dates=<?php echo $eventstart ;?>/<?php echo $eventend ;?>
&details=<?php echo (get_field('summary'));?>
&location=<?php echo (get_field('address'));?>"
target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to my calendar</a>
```

How can this link be set in WORDPRESS on other buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The base URL you are using has never worked in my experience making Google Calendar buttons. Try `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit` instead, like the following:

```
<?php 
$format = "Ymd\THis\Z";
$starttime = get_field('start');
$endtime = get_field('end');
$eventstart = date($format , $starttime);
$eventend = date($format , $endtime);?>

<a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit
?text=<?php the_title(); ?>
&dates=<?php echo $eventstart ;?>/<?php echo $eventend ;?>
&details=<?php echo (get_field('summary'));?>
&location=<?php echo (get_field('address'));?>"
target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to my calendar</a>
```

You should end up with something similar to this:

```
<a href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=Subject&dates=20230113/20230115&details=BodyText&location=123MainSt" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to my calendar</a>
```